# POST request with QWebView

Tags: c++, qt

How can I issue a POST request over a QWebView instance?

Comment: You open some url where post form has, and want to upload some file in the same qwebview window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the information below will help you:

1). Standard Qt example project, called "previewer", which comes with Qt SDK, may help you. For me, the absolute path is:

```
C:\Qt\4.6.2\examples\webkit\previewer
```

QWebView class, as I could test it, supports "post method", i.e. you can free open URL with POST page, and tap on the "Open file" button and after that upload any data.

2). About a month ago a have some kind of a problem with posting data (any files) to server, and here was my **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627949/upload-file-with-post-method-on-qt4)**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a load method which allows you to specify custom QNetworkRequest object and request type (GET, POST etc):
http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwebview.html#load-2