# How to upload file to Amazon S3 in Qt 4

Tags: c++, qt, file-upload, qt4, amazon-s3

How to upload file to Amazon S3 in Qt 4 using their REST API? Maybe there are ready libraries already? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a file using a REST API is just using HTTP POST method. You can already find answer on this question on Stackoverflow - see [Upload file with POST method on Qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627949)

Answer (score 1):

Was messing around that issue yesterday, and found QCloud repo ( on 7 page oF Google ), that is a realy good point to star with...

[repo](https://yousource.it.jyu.fi/thesis-code/thesis-code/trees/master)

[author's summary with some examples and fundamentals](https://jyx.jyu.fi/dspace/bitstream/handle/123456789/40660/URN%3aNBN%3afi%3ajyu-201301071014.pdf?sequence=1)