# unable to post a ZIP file to a server using wininet

Tags: c++, visual-c++, networking, wininet

I am opening file in binary mode using

```
fopen("abhi.zip","rb");
```

and reading contents from it and appending it to header.

as there are many null characters in "abhi.zip"(zipped file)

It is posting data only till it reads a null character.

i am using httpsendrequest(...);

i am struck here,can anyone please help me...

Comment: Post your code to get more accurate responses. Probably you need to encapsulate the binary data somehow since HTML is a text protocol - can you encode as Base64, or use something like XML `CDATA`?

Comment: See related question here, upvote the answer if it works for you. MIME looks like the way to go so +1 for response below, as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516149/how-to-send-mime-over-http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to stick your POST data into the headers, instead, pass it as the `lpOptional` parameter, passing its length in `dwOptionalLength`. You will likely need to encode and wrap your data with the proper MIME boundaries (I could find no clear documentation on whether or not this is needed)

Comment: Thanx alot it worked....i am using loOptional parameter from the beggining but i am using strlen(data) for dwoptionalLength which is giving length less than required length as "data" parameter has NULL character in between....