# Send 2 CSV in JCL

Tags: csv, jcl

I try to send attachment (2 csv files) using JCL.
When I use XMIT all is good
[image]

and I 've got lay out I want.
But when I use IEBGENER:

```
HELO ...                                
MAIL FROM:<user@xxx.COM>                           
RCPT TO:<user@xxx.COM>                             
DATA                                                      
FROM:     userH@xxx.COM                             
TO:       user@xxx.COM                             
SUBJECT:  RACF REPORT                                     
MIME-VERSION: 1.0                                         
CONTENT-TYPE: MULTIPART/MIXED; BOUNDARY="SIMPLE BOUNDARY" 
--SIMPLE BOUNDARY                                         
CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/CSV                                    
CONTENT-DISPOSITION: ATTACHMENT; FILENAME=TEST1.CSV       
                                                      
//         DD DSN=file1.CSV,DISP=SHR    
//         DD *                                           
--SIMPLE BOUNDARY                                         
CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/CSV                                    
CONTENT-DISPOSITION: ATTACHMENT; FILENAME=TEST2.CSV       
                                                      
//         DD DSN=file.CSV,DISP=SHR
```

I 've got something strange:

[image]

Maybe anybody know whats wrong?

Comment: Please look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4656646/624463) to a similar question.   Specifically, I believe you need (at least) to append two hyphens to the last boundary.

Comment: @cschneid hmn. It doesn't work(

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use FTP if you have a ftp server and access to a output directory.
Example from [Submitting FTP requests in batch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu001/ftpreq.htm)

```
//USER28F  JOB ,CARTER,MSGLEVEL=(1,1)
//FTPSTP1  EXEC PGM=FTP,REGION=2048K,
//             PARM='9.67.112.25 (EXIT TIMEOUT 20'
//NETRC    DD  DSN=ANYHLQ.NETRC,DISP=SHR
//OUTPUT   DD  SYSOUT=H
//INPUT    DD  *
type e
mode b
put idss.parts
/*
```

For the PARM parameter target the SMTP server that you have available at your environment.
And as for the NETRC dataset here is the info [NETRC data set info](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu001/netftp.htm)

However if you still want to send it via an email you are missing few things in the job above. Best to lookup here [Send email with attachment on Mainframe using JCL](http://technology-central.org/mainframe/cobol-jcl/send-email-with-attachment-mainframe-using-jcl/)

Regards,
Jarek.